# I want to add a specific field in my table

Tags: django

I have a two user_type students and teachers.
I want to add specific field to teachers and students when i update a profile

```
class UserType(AbstractUser):
    user =models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    USER_TYPE = (
        (1, 'Student'),
        (2, 'Teacher'),
    )
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE)
```

Here I created a Teacher model where i can add extra fields for teacher

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.user_type = 2
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = '', default = '')

    #return the teacher's name
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Similarly I created a Student model to add extra field for users

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.user_type = 1        
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = '', default = '')


    #return the student's name
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type == 2:
            Teacher.objects.create(user=instance)
        elif instance.user_type == 1:
            Student.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.user_type == 2:
        instance.teacher.save()
    elif instance.user_type == "patient":
        instance.student.save()
```

I don't know how to add usertype specific additional information. I couldn't save the instance of teacher and student as a separate table. and also the profile didn't work

Comment: In your signal, you are writing `instance.user_type`, but the instance is referring to the `User` model which has no `user_type` field...

Comment: You may want to read Model Inheritance to improve your idea of `UserType` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Also, `user.user_type = 2` in `Teacher` (and a similar one `Student`) are bad. You should rethink your schema. If you absolutely need `user_type` in the parent's model for filtering purposes, you should put that piece of code inside the creation method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model).